# Vittoria Rubino Pro Slick Road Tire

Tags: tire

I've been riding an ancient set of Conti Ultra Races and get flats every 100 miles or so. What do you guys think of the [Vittoria Rubino Pro Slick Road Tire](http://www.performancebike.com/bikes/Product_10052_10551_1034898_-1_400904__400904#pr-header-50__2528)?

The Contis were 25mm and I'm thinking of getting the 23mm. I'm reading the [previous discussion on the subject](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/what-are-the-benefits-of-700c23-tires/10513#10513) but would appreciate any feedback on the matter.

Comment: I have an Audax bike which came with 25mm Rubinos. No complaints here. The tyres got worn out in the end and I can't actually remember ever getting a flat on them. Replaced them with Corsas, just because I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run Rubino Pros for a few years. They aren't the lightest or fastest tire around, but they last very well and are pretty flat proof for my area (Seattle).