# 23 mm combined with 25 mm tyre in racing

Tags: tire

I met a guy who mixed 23 and 25 mm for his front and rear tyre respectively.

Now thinking about it, I believe it's a pretty good idea since the rear wheel bear a higher proportion of the rider's weight. Wider rear tyres would support more weight with the same pressure as the front. It also helps reduce the wear and tear on the tyre itself.

So why don't bicycle (especially racing) run a slightly wider tyre in the rear, as the rear wheel mostly bear the weight of rider? It makes the ride more comfortable, and not aerodynamically terrible as the front is still 23 mm.

Comment: Why would a racer care about comfort in the first place? Or wear and tear?

Comment: Hi Batman, competitive cyclist care about comfort. Riding 25 mm for 8 hours is a night and day different from 23 mm. Agree that it's not so much for wear and tear, but for training it's a good idea

Comment: Does the rear wheel on racing road bikes really bear that much more weight? As long as the road surface is good there is no reason to use wider tires. For cobblestones they do use wider tires.

Comment: I believe so, as rear tyre requires replacement much more often than the front.

Answer (score 4):

I would be genuinely surprised if it made any real-world difference.  Some racers commit all sorts of voodoo... err... questionable practices on the off chance it might give them an advantage. In terms of 23 vs 25 mm tires, both sizes are frequently used by pro tour teams, if one had a distinct advantage over the other you wouldn't see both sizes being used at the same events.  It terms of aerodynamics, [even for sizes up to 32 mm  there doesn't seem to be much difference in   aerodynamics drag](https://janheine.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/aerodynamics-of-real-world-bicycles/).

In terms of comfort getting the right tire pressure for your body weight will likely have a bigger effect than 2mm gain in the tire width.

Other disadvantages include complications  introduced into the assembly and supply chain for the manufacturer, which would eat into profits.

Answer (score -1):

The bigger question is, what would be the benefits of this setup? If you are willing to sacrifice the few grams of weight and square centimeters of cross section that come with wider tires, why wouldn't you use a wider tire in the front too? The benefits at comfort, grip and possibly rolling resistance apply to front, too.

In my opinion, the bike also looks nicer if both tires are similar. And if you keep spares, the same one goes for both.

Comment: From this http://sheldonbrown.com/tires.html#width, lower rolling resistance would only be possible if the tyre is over inflated.

Comment: Could you point out the exact words? I see only that wider tires should have lower pressure, which is related but does not alone lead to your conclusion.

Comment: The rear wheel runs in dirty air, so size is less of an issue than for the front tyre which is in clean air. That's why you want the front as skinny as possible.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen time trail racers do the opposite and run a 22mm or 23mm tire in back and a 25mm up front.

One reason not to have a larger tire in back is because it's comparatively heavier and all the extra weight is around the circumference of the wheel.  When you are putting power through the crank and trying to spin up the rear wheel, that extra weight is felt and you need more power compared to the effort required when riding a lighter, possibly smaller tire.

One other reason I can think of is that it might actually be more aero to have a larger tire up front when paired with a wide rim, which is the current industry trend.  Every wheel manufacturer seems to find evidence that whatever they are doing is the best.

Answer (score -6):

Racing is all about speed. 25mm tyres have a larger contact area so there is more rolling resistance than a 23mm. It doesn't make a huge difference but it is significant. You wouldn't be competitive on 25s with everyone else runnings 23s.

But for some very tough terrain, such as going over cobblestones, most teams will often run 25s front and back. They  also deflate slightly from the maximum pressure to avoid some of the ride harshness.

I started on 28mm tyres on a commuter and soon went down to 23mm. Didn't notice any difference in tyre wear or comfort. Bike was less effort to ride. Only downside is is that it is more likely to catch a rut in the road, but you ride with a bit more caution.

Comment: How does reducing the pressure avoid punch flats?

Comment: You mean pinch?.I thought this is when the tube gets caught aginst the rim and tears. Seems to happen with a lot of pressue, such as when jumping a gutter. So lower tube pressure should make it less likely.

Comment: Punch = my phone's attempt at pinch :-)

Comment: Pinch flats are indeed caused when the tube gets caught between the rim and an object. Lower pressure makes them more likely.

Comment: That makes more sense, they will be held in place more securely at high pressure. Good to learn something new, thanks @andy256

Comment: I see someone else downvoted before you could update your answer :-(

Comment: The rolling resistance is still part wrong. For otherwise similar tires at similar pressure, wider has less rolling resistance. Now, 28mm tires typically have thicker rubber and coarser casing than 23/25mm ones, but not everyone realizes that. And yes, the part about reducing pressure to avoid pinch flats is completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks @andy256, have edited out pinch flat section. Also what's the deal with anonymous down votes? If you don't state your issue, how can we improve our answers?

Comment: Don't let it bother you - it happens, but not frequently on this site. Whoever it was probably wanted to indicate that they thought this answer was wrong, and didn't have time or inclination to explain. With any luck they'll come by and remove their vote later. On some other SE sites downvotes are *much* more frequent. Just try to make sure that what you write is correct, even if it takes longer to check it's right :-)

Comment: @ojs IMO the jury it still out on the rolling resistance angle. Looks like a nice question to ask, so people can put their arguments.

Comment: The downvote was probably because of "25mm tyres have a larger contact area so there is more rolling resistance than a 23mm." Why would a larger contact area increase rolling resistance?

Comment: I don't have a full physical model at hand, but a wider tyre means more volume, so more friction both from the air and the rubber that contacts the road. It's not hugely noticable on a 25, but step up to a 35mm tyre and it is. Yes @andy256, I get anonymous down votes on other SE sites. I'm happy to admit and ammend my errors. But first you need to point out the problem. The etiquette on down votes here advises they be commented.

Comment: OK, I'm downvoting you too.

Comment: Ojs: Of course a wider tire will have less rolling resistance than a narrow one … *if* you test at the same pressures. The wider one will have much less deformation but also comfort. You’d actually have to evaluate which pressures are required for equal comfort and test at those pressures. Otherwise it’s not really comparable since nobody will ride a 40mm tire at 8bar and it would be unfair to compare it with a 23mm tire at 8bar.

Comment: @KimRyan wider tires are faster. http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/what-are-the-benefits-of-700c23-tires

Comment: @Michael I'm aware of this.

Comment: Wider tyres are faster at equal pressure because the contact surface is smaller. But wider tyres can be ridden at lower pressure for more comfort without risk of pinch or snake-bite punctures but with the downside of higher rolling resistance.

Comment: Yes, wider tyres will have less resistance, but ONLY at equal pressure. But from reading this http://sheldonbrown.com/tires.html#width , a wider tyre is designed for a lower pressure. Just look at the maximum pressure markings on the tyre, usually 120 psi for 23 mm, 100 psi for 28 mm. If you go pack to the physics, pressure = force/area. So to support the same weight of rider, a wider tyre uses a lower pressure and applied over a wider area. The wider contact patch means greater rolling resistance.